# How to find all files that are not of a certain extension?

Tags: bash, scripts, find, automation, file-format

I'd like to delete every file in a directory that is not a .png file. I'd only like to keep pictures, and delete everything else.

Something like this, which obviously doesn't work:

```
for file not in *.png;
do
 rm $file
done
```

How would I go about this? I'd also like to know how to do this with custom strings in filenames, and not just extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash with `extglob` set you can use negative matching:

```
shopt -s extglob # often a default, could be already set
rm *.!(png)
rm !(*keep*|*save*) # everything except files with "keep" or "save" in their name
```

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) for the gory details.

Comment: Tested it, should be rm *.!(png). Other than that, both work great, thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 5):

This would be the equivalent using `find` and negation of the matching option. I strongly recommend to test the result without `-delete` first.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "*.png" -delete
```

Comment: Another great solution. Great for seeing all the files which get deleted. Thanks!

Comment: @GašperČefarin Of course you always have the option to replace the actual action by an `echo` to check the behaviour of the `for` loop. BTW, I just added the `maxdepth` option that got swallowed by my previous edit; it's important in case you don't want subdirectories being affected.